# How to get negative timestamp?

Tags: c++, windows, timestamp, std

I need to convert dates before 1970 to timestamps. I have a correct tm structure but Microsoft's std library mktime can't convert it to negative timestamps. Is there any standard way (no Qt, WinAPI) to get it?

Comment: have you tried to use std::chrono? i recommend using this header only library in addition to it. https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date/blob/master/include/date/date.h

Comment: I tried to find a way using chrono, but failed. How can I use it with tm?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16773285/how-to-convert-stdchronotime-point-to-stdtm-without-using-time-t

Comment: So your advice is to use days_from_civil function?

Comment: look for howard hinnant on youtube he has really good examples on how to use std::chrono, and date time manipulation.

Comment: Could you post the answer (want mark it as solution)?

Comment: Good answer. ;-)  Question:  Are your input dates UTC, or associated with some time zone?

Comment: UTC, all is working now. My hand written function somehow lost 29/02. Thanks for your videos, it is really helpful!